# How do I convert this for loop (python) to C#?

Tags: python, c#, for-loop

`for i in range(math.ceil(-halfrh), math.ceil(halfrh)):`

This is a very simple for loop that I really struggle converting to C#

```
example 1:
halfrh = 2.5
i = -2
i = -1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2

example 2:
halfrh = 1.5
i = -1
i = 0
i = 1
```

Comment: You could use `Enumerable.Range` just note that it takes the starting value and the count instead of the end value.

Comment: What are you struggling with? `range` in python includes the `start` but not the `end`. The equivalent in C# would be looping from `i = Math.Ceiling(-halfrh)` to `i < Math.Ceiling(halfrh)`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in C# would look as follows:

```
for (int i = Math.Ceiling(-halfrh); i < Math.Ceiling(halfrh); i++) {
    …
}
```

But in C# the terminating condition is fully evaluated in every loop and thus you’d usually precompute potentially expensive operations:

```
int upperBound = Math.Ceiling(halfrh);
for (int i = Math.Ceiling(-halfrh); i < upperBound; i++) {
    …
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.'
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'Math.Ceiling(double)'
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'Math.Ceiling(double)'
(the error appears twice)

Comment: @CatOw It works if you declared `halfrh` “correctly”; apparently you chose a type (`float`?) that doesn’t have an overload of `Math.Ceiling`. I suggest declaring your variable as type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Start off the counter at the minumum value, and count up until you reach the maximum value.
I found that using Math.Floor gave the exact results you were looking for, instead of Math.Ceiling.

```
for (int i = (int)-Math.Floor(halfrh); i <= (int)Math.Floor(halfrh); i++)
{
Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

[Math.Floor C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor?view=netcore-3.1/)